# Hadoop 1.x Production Version

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2

I am using **Hadoop-1.0.3 version clusters with hadoop subprojects** installed in it currently for learning purpose .
I want to now ,is any hadoop-1.0.3 version clusters are currently used in any production systems or any companies still using this hadoop1.x versions in production systems,and can i use hadoop tools like hive,sqoop,pig in this 1.x versions in production systems or this tools are supported only above hadoop 2.x versions.Anyonce Please help on this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I guess it's possible : https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/hcat-r0.5.0/rest_server_install.html#Hadoop+Distributed+Cache, you may need some patchs.

Comment: It is better to use yarn in production as it solved most of the issues with hadoop 1.x.Also the tools that you mentioned also support hadoop 1.x as well as hadoop 2.x but it depends on the version you download

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response,can you please assist me, where we will get the production ready version details in hadoop1.x ,because specifically i need to check whether hadoop-1.0.3 is production ready or not ,thats why?